# Converting MySQL Query for Jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I need to run the query below in JQuery Datatable Editor but the syntax is completely different when using Jquery Datatable Editor. Side note, I'm surprised there's no online converter since Jquery Datatable is so popular.

I wanted to use a view instead but I can't use a subquery in a view. Can someone please assist?

```
SELECT
t1.techid,
t1.techname,
t1.manager,
t1.dispatcher,
t1.cellphone,
t2.SC_SCTechID,
t2.BCARNA,
t2.SC_CallStatus,
t2.Serial_ID,
t2.Age,
t2.SC_CallComment,
t2.SC_CallTimestamp,
COALESCE(t3.num_tickets, 0) AS num_tickets
FROM serviceteam t1
LEFT JOIN ato_openservicecalls t2
    ON t1.techid = t2.SC_SCTechID AND t2.SC_CallStatus = 'Dispatch'
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.techid, COUNT(t2.Serial_ID) AS num_tickets
    FROM serviceteam t1
    LEFT JOIN ato_openservicecalls t2
        ON t1.techid = t2.SC_SCTechID
    WHERE t2.SC_CallStatus = 'Dispatch'
    GROUP BY
    t1.techid
) t3
 ON t1.techid = t3.techid
```

The Data:

```
CREATE TABLE `serviceteam` (
  `id` int,
  `techid` varchar(50),
  `techname` varchar(50),
  `manager` varchar(50),
  `dispatcher` varchar(50),
  `cellphone` varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE `ato_openservicecalls` (
  `id` int,
  `SC_SCTechID` varchar(50),
  `SC_CallStatus` varchar(50),
  `BCARNA` varchar(50),
  `Age` varchar(50),
  `SC_CallTimestamp` varchar(50),
  `Serial_ID` varchar(50),
  `SC_CallComment` varchar(50)
);


insert into `serviceteam` VALUES (1, 'tech1', 'name1', 'manager1', 'dispatcher1', 'cellphone1');
insert into `serviceteam` VALUES (2, 'tech2', 'name2', 'manager2', 'dispatcher2', 'cellphone2');
insert into `serviceteam` VALUES (3, 'tech3', 'name3', 'manager3', 'dispatcher3', 'cellphone3');


insert into `ato_openservicecalls` VALUES (1, 'tech1', 'Dispatch', 'customer1', 'age1', 'timestamp1', 'serial1', 'comment1');
insert into `ato_openservicecalls` VALUES (2, 'tech2', 'Dispatch', 'customer2', 'age2', 'timestamp2', 'serial2', 'comment2');
insert into `ato_openservicecalls` VALUES (3, 'tech3', 'callstatus3', 'customer3', 'age3', 'timestamp3', 'serial3', 'comment3');
```

My attempt in Jquery Datatable Editor:

```
Editor::inst( $db, 'serviceteam')
->fields(
Field::inst( 'serviceteam.techid' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
Field::inst( 'serviceteam.techname' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
Field::inst( 'serviceteam.manager' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
Field::inst( 'serviceteam.dispatcher' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
Field::inst( 'serviceteam.cellphone' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
Field::inst( 'serviceteam.serviceteamstatus' )->validator( 'Validate::notEmpty' ),
Field::inst('ato_openservicecalls.SC_SCTechID')->validator("Validate::notEmpty"),
Field::inst('ato_openservicecalls.SC_CallStatus')->validator("Validate::notEmpty"),
Field::inst('ato_openservicecalls.BCARNA')->validator("Validate::notEmpty"),
Field::inst('ato_openservicecalls.Age')->validator("Validate::notEmpty"),
Field::inst('ato_openservicecalls.SC_CallTimestamp')->validator("Validate::notEmpty"),
Field::inst('ato_openservicecalls.Serial_ID')->validator("Validate::notEmpty"),
Field::inst('ato_openservicecalls.SC_CallComment')->validator("Validate::notEmpty")
)
->leftJoin('ato_openservicecalls', 'ato_openservicecalls.SC_SCTechID', '=', 'serviceteam.techid AND (ato_openservicecalls.SC_CallStatus = "Dispatch")')
->process( $_POST )
->json();
```

This query in Jquery Datatable Editor returns everything that i need except the count. I need a column that shows a total count of records where SC_CallStatus = Dispatch for each TechID.